# How can you combine all Vue.js routes, templates and components into one file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to compose a Vue.js example that combines everything into one file. Basically I'm trying to prove the efficiency of a small silo that serves more than one route. This is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index2</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.22/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.0.2/vue-router.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="app">
            <h1>Hello App!</h1>
            <p>
                <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
                <router-link to="/categories">Categories</router-link>
            </p>

            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>

    const Foo = { template: '#foo' }

    const Categories = {
        template: '#Categories',
        data: {
            categories: [{ title: "blah" }, {title:"yack"}]
        },
        methods: {
            saveNew: function(event) {
                alert("boo!");
            }
        }
    }

    const routes = [
        { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
        { path: '/Categories', component: Categories }
    ];

    const router = new VueRouter({
        routes: routes,
        mode: 'history',
        base: '/forums/admin/index2/'
    });

    const app = new Vue({
        router
    }).$mount('#app');

    Vue.config.devtools = true;

</script>

<template id="foo">
    <div>foo</div>
</template>

<template id="Categories">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" name="newCategoryTitle" class="form-control" />
        <input type="button" v-on:click="saveNew" value="AddNew" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="category in categories">{{category.title}}</li>
    </ul>
    <table class="table">
        <tr v-for="category in categories">
            <td>{{category.title}}</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</template>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jeffyjonesx/sd79npwb/1/

Here's the problem: The data in the Categories component does not bind to the template, where I've tried both a ul and a table. Even more weird, if I move the ul to the first thing in the template, it breaks. However, the button handler on the loaded form works.

I feel like I'm getting the declaration of the templates wrong, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Check [Components base example](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Base-Example) and also [data MUST BE a function](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)

Comment: Also templates should be inside [X-Templates](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#X-Templates)

Comment: I've updated [your jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/v6cb27t9/5/)

Comment: @ljubadr What would be the advantage of using an x-template here? The docs say "it can be useful in demos or small applications", but it doesn't say _how_ it's useful. In the case that `<template>` isn't available, sure, but that's doesn't seem to apply here, and I can't think of anything else

Comment: `<template>` is not natively supported in all browsers, more in this [github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2198#issuecomment-173330988)

Comment: I can't get it to work in IE at all, but it's not the template tags, rather it's choking on making the data option a function. The console says `Expected: ':'` at the parentheses for `data()`.

Comment: Nevermind... I keep forgetting IE doesn't like function shorthand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Templates can only have one root element.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element) Vue sees the first element, the `div.form-inline`, and ignores everything else. Wrap the template in a single `<main>` tag (div also works, but semantics!)

```
<template id="Categories">
  <main>
    <div class="form-inline">
      <input type="text" name="newCategoryTitle" class="form-control" />
      <input type="button" v-on:click="saveNew" value="AddNew" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="category in categories">{{category.title}}</li>
    </ul>
    <table class="table">
      <tr v-for="category in categories">
        <td>{{category.title}}</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </main>
</template>
```

Another note, you're using the *production* version of Vue (`vue.min.js`). While developing, use the development version of Vue instead (`vue.js`) to get warnings about issues like this.

Comment: Thanks, I totally read over that with the assumption that the containing template tag _was_ the single root.